# Python 2.7 "import hashlib" segmentation fault

Tags: linux, python-2.7, segmentation-fault, hashlib

Whenever I try to import hashlib in Python 2.7 I get a segmentation fault. I've installed openssl version 1.0.0, pyOpenssl version .10, and recompiled python with the ssl lines uncommented in Modules/Setup, pointing to the correct path for the libraries and include files for openssl.

I've run ldd on all the libraries I can find that might use libssl or libcrypto, and they're all pointing to the same versions of the files.

gdb returns:
`0x0000003d1d0f670 in EVP_PKEY_CTX_dup () from /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0`

Any ideas what might be going on, and how to repair it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hashlib` uses libcrypto for hash algorithms if it can find libcrypto while building python.

I suspect somehow it's ending up using a different libcrypto at runtime vs. build time.

Answer (score -2):

To install libcrypto, you can follow these steps:

1. Determine your operating system. Different operating systems have different package managers and installation methods. Here are a few examples of installation methods for common operating systems:

   - Debian/Ubuntu-based systems (using apt):

     ```
     sudo apt update
     sudo apt install libssl-dev
     ```
   - Red Hat/CentOS-based systems (using yum):

     ```
     sudo yum install openssl-devel
     ```
   - macOS systems (using Homebrew):

     ```
     brew install openssl
     ```
   - Windows systems (using vcpkg):

     - Install the vcpkg tool, which can be found on its GitHub page.
     - Open Command Prompt or PowerShell and navigate to the vcpkg installation directory.
     - Run the following command to install libcrypto:

       ```
       .\vcpkg install openssl
       ```

   Choose the appropriate installation method for your operating system and make sure you have the necessary permissions to install packages.
2. After installing libcrypto, you may need to inform the compiler and linker to use it during compilation and linking. This typically involves setting the relevant environment variables or compiler options, depending on the programming language and build system you're using.

   - For C/C++ compilers, you can use the `-lcrypto` option to instruct the compiler to link the libcrypto library. For example:

     ```
     gcc -o myprogram myprogram.c -lcrypto
     ```
   - For other programming languages and build systems, consult their documentation or configuration files to find out how to set the library linking options.

Note that during the libcrypto installation, any required dependencies may also be installed automatically. The installation process may vary depending on your operating system and package manager. Make sure your system is up to date and install any additional dependencies as needed.

Comment: This appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it, as [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was AI-generated, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify issues.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).